# PickerView in custom cell delegate where my tableVIew is

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview, uipickerview, viewcontroller

I want to implement picker that is in my custom cell, in my VC that has the tableView, I can't figure out how to reference that specific picker (because I have other 2), so if I try to make a switch statement with "did select row" I can't reference that specific picker that is in tableCell.
thank you

Comment: Can you make your custom cell the picker view delegate? Posting code and more detail might help answer this.

Comment: I could delegate in my custom cell, but can't find a way to pass the data to tableview and update it when did select row

Comment: @CristianTamborrell - In general, if you have interactive elements in a table view cell, ***that cell class*** should handle the interaction and inform the controller that something changed. At that point, the controller should update the data. It *sounds* like you are trying to have the controller *ask the cell* for information. However, it's not entirely clear what you are asking... try to provide more detail about your cell / table view / controller structure, and describe exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIPickerView inside your UITableViewCell class like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    let list1:[String] = ["iOS","Swift","Xcode"]
    let list2:[String] = ["android","Kotlin","Android Studio"]
    let list3:[String] = ["React","Javascript","VSCode"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}

//MARK: PICKERVIEW DELEGATE AND DATASOURCE
extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        switch pickerView.tag {
        case 0:
            return list1.count
        case 1:
            return list2.count
        case 2:
            return list3.count
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        switch pickerView.tag {
        case 0:
            return list1[row]
        case 1:
            return list2[row]
        case 2:
            return list3[row]
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
                  didSelectRow row: Int,
                  inComponent component: Int) {
        switch pickerView.tag {
        case 0:
            lbl.text = list1[row]
        case 1:
            lbl.text = list2[row]
        case 2:
            lbl.text = list3[row]
        default:
            break
        }
        
    }
}

//MARK: - TABLEVIEW DELEGATE DATASOURCE
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomPickerTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomPickerTableViewCell
        cell.pickerview.delegate = self
        cell.pickerview.dataSource = self
        cell.pickerview.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 140
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
    }
    
}
```

The tableview cell Class:

```
class CustomPickerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerview: UIPickerView!
    
}
```

Make the storyboard design look like this:

[image: storyboard screenshot]